# How to calculate the speed of an object

Tags: python, algorithm, variables, time

I tried to calculate the current position of a car and it worked pretty well so far. Indeed there is some big jump in time sometimes and I don't know why.

Example: 
I wrote a function which reseted the ´self.comulatedWay´ variable, but after the reset the init value sometimes starts already with arround 1000 and not from 0 again as expected? The value of the speed is fine. It has to be something with the time...

Maybe its the whole algorithm which is pretty shitty? Haven't had a better idea to realize it..

Here is the code for tracking the position.
Speed in mm/s (not constant)
Way in mm

```
import threading
import time

class car:

    def __init__(self, speed):
        self.t0 = 0
        self.speed = speed  # current speed of the car
        self.comulatedWay = 0
        threading.Thread(target=self.locationCalc, name="ThreadLocationCalc", ).start()   

    # calc the current position of the car in mm
    def locationCalc(self):
        self.t0 = time.time()
        while True:
            t1 = time.time()
            deltaTime = t1 - self.t0
            self.t0 = t1
            way = self.speed * deltaTime
            self.comulatedWay = way + self.comulatedWay
```

Comment: You are calculating the distance since t0, but accumulating in self.comulatedWay. Instead, calculate the distance traveled since the last time

Comment: sry I don't get it?

Comment: You're adding the full distance every time.  Using simple numbers for clarity: say you started at position 0 at time 0, then at time 5 you had travelled 5, so you add 5. So far so good, that's where you are. Then at time 10 you've travelled 5 more and are at a position of 10. Your code should add the 5 more that you've travelled, but instead it's adding the 10 total that you've traveled, so now it says you're at 15 instead of 10.

Comment: Are you sure? I mean  'way' is the piece I just travelled and in the next step, I just add the piece to the whole way travelled?

Comment: But every time you calculate the distance traveled from t0, not the distance traveled since the last time you calculated

Comment: Yes you are right, there was a copy error when I inserted the code here. I fixed it accordingly  - that's now the identical code where the error occurs... still

Comment: and the error occurs just sometimes.. not every time I reset the self.comulatedWay... that's the weird thing.